# Use Outer Reference Inside Module

Tags: rust

Consider:

```rust
struct Outer { ... }

mod Inner {
    let outer: Outer { ... }
}
```

How does one "import" `Outer` into `Inner`? As it stands, Rust will complain `no external crate "Outer"`.

Attempted solutions include `mod { use Outer; ... }`.

Comment: `use super::Outer;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in Rust, you can always use qualified paths. That means if `Outer` as a type didn't work, `use Outer` will not work either.

To access the parent module, use the keyword `super`:

```rust
let outer: super::Outer;
```

It refers to the parent module, so we say "from the parent module, take `Outer`".

Another way, not recommended for this case but useful to know in other cases, is to track the parent module path down from the crate root. Assuming your parent module is inside the module `b` that is inside `a`, you can write `crate::a::b::parent_module::Outer`.

Comment: Is there a reason why the language authors didn't make outer references referrable by default? What is the disadvantage to adding "use super::*" to every mod?

Comment: @Test The same reason modules are used: it pollutes the namespace and may create a name collision. Glob imports are generally forbidden for this reason (except for preludes).